# Prism 6.1.0 MefBootstrapper's implementation: CreateShell method throws an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

I'm using Prism 6.1.0 for the first time.
I created a new WPF project just to try the taste of the newest prism.

My shell looks this way:

```
<Window x:Class="Prism.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prism"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Shell"
    Height="300"
    Width="300">
<Grid Background="HotPink"></Grid>
```

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Windows;

namespace Prism
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Shell.xaml
    /// </summary>
    [Export]
    public partial class Shell : Window
    {
        public Shell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Bootstrapper:

```
using Prism.Mef;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Windows;

namespace Prism
{
    public class MyBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
        }
        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();
            Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }
        protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
            AggregateCatalog.Catalogs
                .Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MyBootstrapper).Assembly));
        }
    }
}
```

and App c# code is:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace Prism
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            (new MyBootstrapper()).Run();
        }
    }
}
```

After this line:
[image]
I have an exception:
***Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationCore.dll
Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.***
[image]

Does someone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that your window constructor is invoked by another thread. In WPF world every control: window, button, etc. must be created by a single special thread called STAThread. Furthermore, only STAThread can access UI controls (if another thread does this, same `InvalidOperationExcepiotion` would be thrown). So it looks like you invoke a new thread somewhere. I can't see a mistake in your code, I also don't know whether your container starts any thread. But make sure you don't create any suspicious thread in your code.

Also look for StartupURI in App.xaml. It shouldn't be set if you use DI container. But it is not this I think.

I created an example app, I copied your code and it works. So your error is something strange.

Comment: When I've used the prism 4.0 it works.
Thanks for attempt.

Comment: I have tested it on newest Prism 6.2